# DRIVEN vs. BEING DRIVEN in this sentence ( reduced adverbial clause)

Tags: passive-voice, subordinate-clauses

**Example sentence**:

> Before the kids were driven to the mall, they had some sandwiches in a convenience store.

Now if we reduce the adverbial clause of the sentence, **which one** will be the correct construction between **1** and **2**, if not both of them?

**1)** Before **driven** to the mall, the kids had some sandwiches in a convenience store.

**2)** Before **being driven** to the mall, the kids had some sandwiches in a convenience store.

My next question is, **how to determine** whether we should use the 'being' before a past participle in any sentence similar to the given example above?

Answer (score 2):

2 is right; 1 is wrong. You use a present participle not a past participle after "before". "driven" is past tense; "being driven" is [present passive participle](https://www.english-grammar-today.com/present-passive-participle.html).

Similarly "Before driving to the mall, the adults had some sandwiches in a convenience store." is right because again you have the present participle "driving".

Note that there are many other constructions with "before", which have different grammar.